# Where is better place to declare local variable which is used only inside one function?

Tags: c++, oop

```cpp
class MyClass{
   public:
      MyClass();
      void memberFunction();
   private:
      int myVariable_;  // can i declare it here?
};

void MyClass::memberFunction(){
      int myVariable_; //or here?
}


//variable "myVariable_" is used only inside "memberFunction()"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it's only used within a function, and it doesn't need to *exist* longer than that function, then you're talking about a local variable.

If you need it to persist between calls, you need a property.

In other words, do you need the value stored in `myVariable_` to persist to the next call?

Comment: I need value in myVariable_ only in one call the function.

Comment: If you need it to persist between calls, you can also declare it locally as `static`

Comment: I should keep this variable only inside the function. Thank you :)

Comment: @IWonderWhatThisAPIDoes True, but that persists between *all* calls, not just calls from the same object.

Answer (score 0):

You should keep in mind The Principle of Least Privilege. It means every thing should be encapsulated where it is needed.For example, If you need a variable that must be accessible within the function, it suppose to be in the function. If a function is not allowed to change the data, it must be declared `const`.

This article may help you understanding [Here](https://www.embedded.com/how-to-write-secure-c-c-application-code-for-your-embedded-design-part-1/).